# Android Studio Gradle NDK buildFlavor ignoring processor type

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I have some problem with gradle and Baidu Push library.

In our app we use buildFlavor for different processor type,

```
  productFlavors {
        arm {
            versionCode Integer.parseInt("8" + defaultConfig.versionCode)
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi"
            }
        }
        x86 {
            versionCode Integer.parseInt("6" + defaultConfig.versionCode)
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86"
            }
        }
        mips {
            versionCode Integer.parseInt("4" + defaultConfig.versionCode)
            ndk {
                abiFilter "mips"
            }
        }
        armv7 {
            versionCode Integer.parseInt("2" + defaultConfig.versionCode)
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but Baidu Push library provide only arm and mips NDK support library, x86 did not need any .so for working, and when we try to build app with x86, we have error [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS].

Any idea, how we can ignore ndk library for this processor type?

Refering to Baidu push library documentation: "all x86 devices support arm so" what does it mean?

Comment: do not build for x86 at all ... if `"all x86 devices support arm so" ` is true(AFAIK it is) then it is true for your library too ...

Comment: That the point, why i wrote this question. 
If there any way, to build project with x86 productFlavor and ignoring INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're setting the higher version code to an armeabi build. If you do that, it's the armeabi APK that will get distributed even to x86 devices, because x86 devices also support running armeabi/armeabi-v7a APKs. You should give the highest version code to your x86 APK.

Anyway, you can run arm libs on x86 devices but you can't mix them. That means that if you cannot get x86 versions of all your libs, you should unfortunately abandon it and publish only the ARM one.

You can also tell to your library vendor that they should publish an x86 version of their lib since not doing so prevents you to correctly build x86 versions of your APKs.